# Problem with conversion from className * to className &(and the reverse)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, visual-c++, reference

Can someone , for the love of god please help me. I've been stuck on this for hours
This is the "father" .h file , which i am **NOT**allowed to alter at all

```
//------------ Declarations for List traits used in Test1 in main.cpp

template <typename T>
class ListTraits
{
public:
    virtual unsigned int size() = 0;
    virtual ListTraits& insert(const T& item) = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

//------------ Declarations for List traits used in Test2 in main.cpp
template <typename T>
class ListTraitsExtended
{
public:
    virtual const T* getCurrentElement() const = 0;
    virtual void advance() = 0;
    virtual void rewind() = 0;
};
```

And this is the "child" .h file ,

```
#include "ListTraits.h"
#include <array>


template <typename T>
class List : public ListTraits<T>
{
protected:

    std::array<int, 7> data;

public:
    
    unsigned int size() override{
        return 0;
    }
    void print() override {

    }
    List & insert(const T& item) override {
        return this;
        
    }
};
```

Where I always get this error:

**'return' cannot convert from List * to List &**

If I do

return *this;

I still get errors...

What exactly am I doing wrong?I cant wrap my head around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List& List::insert(const T &item)` is declared to return a reference to `List`. `this` is a pointer to `List`. To return a reference to List, return `*this`:

```
List & insert(const T& item) override {
    return *this;
}
```